# How to split a string in Python without redundant output

Tags: python

I've been trying to split a string using a regular expression as a separator, but the output of `string.split` appears to contain some redundant results.

```
import re;
replaceArray = '((Replace the string)|((in|inside|within) the string)|(with the string))'
stringToSplit = '(Replace the string arr1 in the array arr2 with the array arr3)'
print(re.split(replaceArray, stringToSplit))
```

I expected the split string to look like this, without any overlapping results:

```
['Replace the string', ' arr1 ', 'in the string', ' arr2 ', 'with the string', ' arr3']
```

But instead, the array of split strings contained some redundant results, which appear to overlap with the other matched strings:

```
['', 'Replace the string', 'Replace the string', None, None, None, ' arr1 ', 'in the string', None, 'in the string', 'in', None, ' arr2 ', 'with the string', None, None, None, 'with the string', ' arr3']
```

Is there any way to prevent these redundant and overlapping results from being included in the output of `string.split`?

Comment: `the string` in your `replaceArray` is supposed to be `the array` to match your output, right?

Comment: @poke Actually, `the array` is supposed to be replaced with `the string`. I've fixed the typo now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have capturing groups in your regex the results of [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) will include those capturing groups.  Add `?:` to the beginning of all of your groups to make them non-capturing.  Several of those groups are not actually necessary, try the following:

```
replaceArray = 'Replace the string|(?:in|inside|within) the string|with the string'
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) on `re.split`:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
>   groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

I think you want to use non-capturing groups in your regex.
That is, instead of using `(...)`, use `(?:...)`

Answer (score 1):

Matching groups prepended with `?:` are non-capturing groups and will not appear in the output. Furthermore, you probably don’t want to use `re.split` here but `re.match` instead—you’re not really interested in splitting the string but instead you want to extract those groups out of it.

```
>>> expr = '\((Replace the array (.*?)) ((?:in|inside|within) the array (.*?)) (with the array (.*?))\)'
>>> re.match(expr, stringToSplit).groups()
('Replace the array arr1', 'arr1', 'in the array arr2', 'arr2', 'with the array arr3', 'arr3')
```

Or

```
>>> expr = '\((Replace the array) (.*?) ((?:in|inside|within) the array) (.*?) (with the array) (.*?)\)'
>>> re.match(expr, stringToSplit).groups()
('Replace the array', 'arr1', 'in the array', 'arr2', 'with the array', 'arr3')
```

Comment: The second example has the output that I need, so it seems to be the best solution.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Why would you want to *split* it? Splitting would usually mean that you have some kind of separator and you are actually interested in what that separator is separating. That doesn’t seem to be the case here. You seem to want to get the information out of that string, and for that `match` is the proper solution.

Comment: The second solution works very well, but `expr` would be easier to read if I could write it as multiple regular expressions instead of combining it into one regular expression.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Well, before putting it into `re.match` (or `re.compile`) it’s just a simple string. So if it helps you, you can create separate strings first and then concatenate them.